# NSolve and FindRoot unable to solve equation

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve the equation below for x and neither `NSolve` nor `FindRoot` are giving me a solution. Any ideas?

```
tD=100;
pwCD=0.7938
NSolve[pwCD == 
 x (1 - Exp[-tD/(100 x)]) - 
    0.336885 Exp[-0.617284 (ln[tD/(100 x)] - 1)^2] && x>0, x]
```

and

```
tD=100;
pwCD=0.7938
FindRoot[pwCD == 
   x (1 - Exp[-tD/(100 x)]) - 
    0.336885 Exp[-0.617284 (ln[tD/(100 x)] - 1)^2], {x, 0.1}]
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are not using the correct syntax for log, which is `Log` not `ln`. Check [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Log.html) for details.

Once you make this correction, everything works fine as it should.

```
NSolve[pwCD == x (1 - Exp[-tD/(100 x)]) - 
    0.336885 Exp[-0.617284 (Log[tD/(100 x)] - 1)^2] && x > 0, x]
```

> {{x -> 2.54874}}

```
FindRoot[pwCD == x (1 - Exp[-tD/(100 x)]) - 
   0.336885 Exp[-0.617284 (Log[tD/(100 x)] - 1)^2], {x, 0.1}]
```

> {{x -> 2.54874}}